# Solution of this differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, integration, differential-calculus, derivations

I wonder if it is possible to solve analytically the following equation

$$
\dot{\alpha}_t = -\frac{2}{m} \alpha^2_t + \frac{1}{2m} (\alpha_t - \alpha_t^*)^2
$$

Where $\alpha_t$ is a complex function, $\alpha_t^*$ is its complex conjugate and $\dot{\alpha}_t$ is the time derivative.

All the best!

Comment: What is the significance of the subscript? Would it not have been preferable to use a simpler notation?

Comment: just means that $\alpha_t = \alpha(t)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this can be integrated explicitly.  First, notice that, since $m\not=0$, we can write $\alpha(t) = 2m\bigl(x(t)+iy(t)\bigr)$, in which case, the given equation becomes
$$
\dot x + i\,\dot y = -4(x + iy)^2 + (2iy)^2 = -4 x^2 - i\,(8xy),
$$
so $\dot x = -4x^2$ and $\dot y = -8 xy$.  Thus, by standard ODE techniques,
$$
x(t) = \frac{x(0)}{(1+4x(0)\,t)}\quad\text{and}\quad
y(t) = \frac{y(0)}{(1+4x(0)\,t)^2}\,.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please explain me how do you solve the second ODE $\dot{y} = -8xy$. I think because x depends on t is necessary to solve using separation of variables something like $dy/y = -8 x(t) dt$

Comment: @user38747:  Yes.  Separation of variables is exactly what you should do, after you have solved $\dot x = -4x^2$.  Alternatively, you can check that the equations imply that  $y/x^2$ is constant, since its derivative is zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert!